# Gradle запуск задачи после сборки всех модулей

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Есть проект, в котором есть главный модуль и саб модули. Нужно выполнить задачу которая собирает fat jar из всех сабмодулей + главный модуль. Сейчас я могу это сделать по отдельности, то есть запустить build, а потом вручную запустить task.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы этот таск автоматически запускался после сборки ВСЕХ модулей. Как это можно сделать ?

PS этот вариант выполняется после сборки основного модуля, когда сабмодули ещё не собрались, так что пожалуйста не надо его предлагать

```
tasks.build.finalizedBy createFatJar
```

Comment: Как так получается, что главный модуль не имеет в зависимостях саб модули?

Comment: @Mister_Jesus, главный модуль содержит в себе всю логику, и делает он её с интерфейсами. Модули же просто имплементируют эти интерфейсы, это даёт возможность не писать код заново для каждой платформы (используется для майнкрафта, там есть Spigot,Spone,Bungee и для каждой платформы было бы неудобно начинать всё заново)

Comment: Тогда просто сделать так, что бы `createFatJar` был зависим от дочерних тасков `build`. Этого будет достаточно. К сожалению, нет способа сделать такой трюк как аккумулировать результаты разных тасков с помощью `finalizeBy` (Я тоже такое искал).

Comment: @Mister_Jesus, можно выполнить код после сборки с помощью buildFinished{}, но как там выполнить таск type: jar

Comment: Проще выполнить таск `createFatJar`, который будет зависеть от нужных тасков, чем триггерить какой-то таск по окончанию предыдущего  и пытатся все это многообразие синхронизировать.